# Seed sequence initialization in initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, random-seed

I am currently trying to implement a random number generator (class) which is using the acceptance rejection method. I therefore need different C++11 random number distributions (in my case a normal distribution and a uniform distribution). I want to make the random numbers as good as possible and hence wanted to use the following to build the functions:

```
 [...]
 #include <random>
 #include <vector>
 [...]
 std::vector<int> seeds(16);   
 std::mt19937 mt;
 std::minstd_rand seed_rng(101); // random seed  
 for(size_t i=0;i<16;++i) seeds[i]=seed_rng();
 std::seed_seq seq(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());
 mt.seed(seq);
 rng_normal = std::bind(ndist, std::ref(mt));
 [...]
```

This works perfectly. But when i try to put all this now in a constructor, i can't use the initialization of the seed sequence any longer. I checked c++ reference, but only came across the std::seed_seq::generate, which is not the proper solution.
Is there a way to construct the seed_seq in my init list after filling the vector?
For a reference to seed_seq, see here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq
Thank you ahead, for any suggestions!

Comment: What is problem with placing this code in a constructor? Or are you asking you can get everything done in the initialization list?

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, sorry. I wanted to get everything done in the initialization list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not interested in retaining the `seed_seq` instance used for constructing the `mt19937`, you could do something like this:

```
 struct foo
 {
    std::mt19937 mt;
    std::normal_distribution<> ndist;
    std::function<decltype(mt)::result_type()> rng_normal;

    foo()
    : mt{make_mersenne_twister()}
    , rng_normal{std::bind(ndist, std::ref(mt))}
    {}

    static std::mt19937 make_mersenne_twister()
    {
        std::minstd_rand seed_rng(std::random_device{}()); // random seed
        std::vector<int> seeds(16);

        std::generate(seeds.begin(), seeds.end(), seed_rng);

        std::seed_seq seq(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());
        return std::mt19937{seq};
    }
 };
```

I replaced your seed (`101`) with [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device).

The problem with retaining the `seed_seq` is that it is neither copyable nor moveable, so delegating its construction to a function like I am with the Mersenne Twister is not possible.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62391d3924fd78a7)

Comment: Vote up! Thanks, that solution should in fact work for me! I think i will search while the seed_seq is actually not movable nor copyable, since I guess this has it's reasons...

Comment: @LeoW. Since you're new and your comment indicates my answer helped, I'll point you to the FAQ on how [accepting a useful answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that your improvement is worth very much. The single value (and default) constructor for std::mt19937 is specified in the C++ Standard. It amounts to something like

```
static constexpr size_t WS = 32;
static constexpr result_type IM = 1812433253;
static constexpr result_type default_seed = 5489u;

explicit mt19937(result_type value = default_seed)
{
    state[0] = value;
    for (int i = 1; i != state_size; ++i)
    {
        state[i] = i + IM * (state[i - 1] ^ (state[i - 1] >> (WS - 2)));
    }
}
```

So, it uses an XOR-SHIFT random number generator to fill up the state array. Given the people who were involved in coming up with this seeding algorithm and the people who worked on getting `<random>` into the Standard, I think it is a safe bet to assume they were aware of std::minstd_ran but found the above superior for seeding the Mersenne Twister.